# Can this monstrous expression be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\sqrt{\left( r_d \cos\left(\frac{-4(C - X) \csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right) + r_p \left(\frac{2C \tan⁡(α) - 4 (C - X) \csc⁡(2α))}{Z}\right) \sin\left(\frac{-4 (C - X) csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right) - m X \tan⁡(α) \sin\left(\frac{-4 (C - X) \csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right)\right)^2 + \left( r_d \sin\left(\frac{4(C - X) \csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right) - r_p \left(\frac{2C \tan⁡(α) - 4 (C - X) \csc⁡(2α))}{Z}\right) \cos\left(\frac{-4 (C - X) csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right) + m X \tan⁡(α) \cos\left(\frac{-4 (C - X) \csc⁡(2α)}{Z}\right)\right)^2}$

- $r_d = r_p + m X - m C$
- $r_p = \frac {m Z}{2}$
- $m$ is positive
- $α$ is between $0$ and $\frac π 4$
- $Z$ is a positive integer
- $X$ is between -1 and +1
- $C$ is between 1 and 1.5

I've been staring at this until I'm cross-eyed, but I can't find any way to break it down. It's not for a class, so I don't have any resources to call upon.

Context:

I'm trying to find the radius of a point on the curve defined by the parametric expressions
$$x = r_d \cos(γ) + r_p \left(\frac{2C \tan(α)} Z + γ\right) \sin(γ) - m X \tan(α) \sin(γ),$$
$$y = r_d \sin(γ) - r_p \left(\frac{2C \tan(α)} Z + γ\right) \cos(γ) + m X \tan(α) \cos(γ)$$

Specifically, the point at $γ = \frac{-4(C - X) \csc⁡(2α)}{Z}$. My instinct for solving that was to plug in the value and use the Pythagorean theorem, which created the expression that is the subject of this question. If there's a better way to find this radius, I would love to try it out.

Update: Looking to simplify the base expressions, I can expand the instances of $r_d$ and $r_p$ and then factor out the $m$ from all three terms, and I can factor out the $\sin$ and $\cos$ from the last two terms, but I can't see how to use that to any advantage...

Comment: that's really monstrous!

Comment: @Tojrah Right? It's been frustrating me for days now.

Comment: Please provide context -- how did you arrive at this expression? Adding the (full) derivation may help us see the bigger problem and there may be an alternative method to solve it rather than dealing with the expression above.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I've added some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often much better to simplify as soon as possible. In this case, the parameterized $x$ and $y$ values at the specified value $\gamma_0 := -4(C-X)\csc(2\alpha)/Z$ reduces fairly nicely:

$$\begin{align}
x &=\tfrac12 mZ \left(\;\cos\gamma_0 + \gamma_0 \cos\alpha \sin(\alpha+\gamma_0)\;\right) \tag1\\[4pt]
y &=\tfrac12 mZ \left(\;\sin\gamma_0 - \gamma_0 \cos\alpha \cos(\alpha+\gamma_0)\;\right) \tag2
\end{align}$$

From there, we easily get
$$x^2+y^2 = \tfrac14m^2Z^2\left(\;1 + \gamma_0 \sin 2 \alpha + \gamma_0^2\cos^2\alpha\;\right) \tag3$$
(Conveniently, there are no $\gamma$s inside the trig functions.)

If you like, you can expand $1=\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha$ and $\sin2\alpha=2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$, regroup, and write
$$x^2+y^2 = 
\tfrac14m^2Z^2\left(\;\left(\gamma_0\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha\right)^2+\cos^2\alpha\;\right) \tag4$$

At this point, expanding $\gamma_0$ explicitly to $-4(C-X)\csc(2\alpha)/Z$ doesn't seem to give anything particularly pretty, so I'll leave that to the reader. $\square$

---

As a bit of a prequel, just substituting $r_d\to r_p+mX-mC$and $r_p\to mZ/2$ into OP's parametric equations gives the simplification
$$\begin{align}
x &= \tfrac12 mZ \left(\;
  \cos\gamma + \gamma \sin\gamma +\gamma_0 \sin\alpha\cos(\alpha+\gamma)
  \;\right) \tag{0.1}\\[4pt]
y &= \tfrac12 mZ \left(\;
  \sin\gamma - \gamma \cos\gamma +\gamma_0 \sin\alpha \sin(\alpha+\gamma)
  \;\right) \tag{0.2}
\end{align}$$
with $\gamma_0$ as above. From these, we get
$$x^2  + y^2 = \tfrac14 m^2Z^2 \left(\; 
1 + \gamma_0 \sin2\alpha + \gamma^2\cos^2\alpha + (\gamma-\gamma_0)^2 \sin^2\alpha \;\right) \tag{0.3}$$
When $\gamma=\gamma_0$, we have that $(0.1)$, $(0.2)$, $(0.3)$ reduce to $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$.

Comment: How do you get to that set of parametric expressions? When I plot that curve, it doesn't line up with the curve from my parametric expressions...

Comment: @Lawton: I wasn't clear; my apologies. My $(1)$ and $(2)$ aren't simplifications of the parameterization, *per se*; they're simplifications of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates *for the specified value of $\gamma=-4(C-X)\csc(2\alpha)/Z$*. (That is, they're the values squared and added in the original monster expression.) Effectively, I made the substitution $X\to C+\tfrac14 \gamma Z \sin2\alpha$, along with the $r_d$ and $r_p$ substitutions, since the expressions happen to be prettier written in terms of $\gamma$ rather than $X$ and $C$.

Comment: Plotting your expanded expression (4) for $x^2+y^2$ (with $γ$ as the horizontal axis) gives ALMOST the same result as plotting the sum of the squares of my x and y functions. Plotting the unexpanded (3) version gives a very different graph. I'm not sure where things are going wrong, but your answer is definitely close.

Comment: In fact, for $X=C=1$ and $α=0$ your (4) expression is identical to the plot of my messy expression. I'm still working on seeing if I can tweak your expression to work for more values for those variables.

Comment: @Lawton: *"Plotting your expanded expression $(4)$ [...] (with $\gamma$ as the horizontal axis)"* ... $\gamma$ isn't a "variable" in my expressions, so plotting the expressions as if they're functions of $\gamma$ doesn't make sense. In my expressions, $\gamma$ is the *specific* value $-4(C-X)\csc(2\alpha)/Z$, so my $(1)$ and $(2)$  give the coordinates of a *specific point*. ... Perhaps it would help if I replaced "$\gamma$" with, say, "$\gamma_0$" to help convey its non-variability.

Comment: I think I understand your answer better now. Plugging $(−4(C−X)csc(2α)/Z)$ into the parametric expressions (1) and (2) does produce the correct point. But plugging it into expressions (3) and (4) does not seem to produce the correct value for that point's distance from the origin. Maybe I'm still doing something wrong?

Comment: Never mind, I missed a set of parentheses. Everything checks out now!

Comment: Is there any chance you'd have some insight for a related question I've asked? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791094/how-do-i-find-the-intersection-of-an-involute-gears-involute-face-curves-and-tr

Comment: @Lawton: There's a chance, but I don't think I'd get to it before weekend.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, here and now and any you might have in the future!